# Pocket PC doesn't connect to SQL after morning hours

Tags: c#, sql-server

So we have an in-house program written in C# running on a Socket Mobile Pocket PC (SoMo650) with Windows Mobile 5. In the past few weeks the device has been VERY spotty in connecting to our SQL server database. Most mornings it works fine, but around 10:00 am (give or take half an hour) it just stops connecting completely; only working afterward on the bluest of moons. The program works fine on other devices 24/7, it's only the PPC that's having problems. The next morning it starts working fine again until the same ~10:00 am. Here's the error I message I get (I typed it out by hand, so sorry for any typos) :

```
ProgramZ.exe
SqlException

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.Tdsparser.Connect()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen()
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal()
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill()
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill()
at ProgramZ.ProgramZTableAdapters.qryWarehousesTableAdapter.GetWarehouse()
at ProgramZ.frmCollection.frmCollection_Load()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form._SetVisibleNotify()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Visible()
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
at ProgramZ.Program.Main()
```

Any ideas what's going on? The package sql.ppc.wce5.armv4i is installed on the device (that package is needed for it to connect to SQL). We've tried restarting the server, reinstalling the software, a factory reset on the PPC, and still no luck. Here's some more info on the device itself:

```
Manufacture: Socket Mobile, Inc
Product ID: SoMo650
CPU: ARM920T PXA270

Windows Mobile 5.0 with the Messaging and Security Feature Pack
OS 5.1.478 (Build 15706.3.5.2)
```

---

EDIT Some requested information: When debugging, the error message is "SqlException was unhandled". That's it. When I click on details, I get the following info:

```
[System.Data.SqlCLient.SqlException]  {"SqlException"}
Class                                 20
Errors                                {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}
InnerException                        null
LineNumber                            0
Message                               "SqlException"
Number                                6
Procedure                             "ConnectionOpen(Connect())."
Server                                "ServerName"
Source                                ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
StackTrace                            "at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError()"...
State                                 0
```

The program is set up with a typical ADO connection. The connection string is like so:

```
Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=ProgramZDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_write;Password=password
```

This is what's going on in the program's code when the error is thrown (this is from the Visual Studio-created dataset) :

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
public virtual ProgramZ.qryWarehousesDataTable GetWarehouse() {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
    ProgramZ.qryWarehousesDataTable dataTable = new ProgramZ.qryWarehousesDataTable();
    this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable); // <-- this is where the error is thrown
    return dataTable;
}
```

The device is connected via WiFi to our SqlServer 2000. There are about 5 more databases running on the server, about 3 of which are being used on a regular basis (as in multiple times a day). One of them powers an ERP system that's being used by 10+ people at any given time. There's a decent amount of traffic to the server, but it seems to be handling it fine (no issues found in the Task Manager). This Pocket PC is the only device that uses the "ProgramZDatabase". I am unaware of any backups or reports that are taking place during these errors.

I think a connection timeout might be worth investigating. I've never messed with editing a timeout; any advice on that?

Comment: *What* is the exception *message*? Most likely it's a timeout btu what exactly does it say? What you posted is just the stack trace. Most likely there is a networking issue. *How* does the device connect to the server? Cable, WiFi? What else is going on around that time? The call stack shows that the connection failed to open. In any case, you should never assume that the network is reliable and add retry logic to try and open the connection again if it fails the first time

Comment: What is the connection timeout? Could it be that it was changed to a value that is too short when there's a lot of traffic? Is the database under stress at that time? Is anyone running a backup or processing reports?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the response; I've edited my post to provide more info. Let me know if there's anything else I should provide.

Comment: WiFi is *unreliable*. Packets *will* be dropped, especially if there's noise or an obstruction, eg a delivery truck coming in at 10 am, lots of employees opening up their laptops at the same time etc. In any case, without code it's impossible to help. The only general advice one can give is, to change your code to retry the operation a few times if it fails the first time.